Name for matrix $A \in GL(n)$ s.t. $A^TBA =I$?
If matrix $B$ is symmetric positive definite, is there some name for the matrix $A \in GL(n)$ that turns $B$ into the identity by conjugate action? i.e. $A^TBA =I$?

I don't know if they have a special name but all such matrices are given by $A = \sqrt{B}^{-1}U$ where $U \in O(n)$. These are the linear isometries $(\mathbb{R}^n, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{I_n})\to (\mathbb{R}^n, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_B)$ where $\langle x,y\rangle_B = x^TBy$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
